# does KVM has the same tool like vmware tools?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

VMWARE has vmtools to enhance VM performance. Does KVM has the same tool to enhance its VM?

If so, how to install such tools? thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, vmware tools provide paravirtualization support to the guest operating system. The equivalent for KVM is virtio. Drivers are available for linux and windows:
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing at the moment.

Comment: ok...is the performance actually the same? I mean KVM meets this requirement through a different way from vmware tools?

Answer (score 0):

One of the big advantage of VMware is the comprehensive operation and maintenance applications (GUI-based). That's definitely a value-add of VMware tools but at high price (licenses).

Ubuntu w/ KVM seems to have better performance compared to VMware. The challenge here is more related to manageability. Command line provides as well a lot of possibilities but the VMware GUI's are more human readable.

Of course, it depends about the use case and the experience of your administrator but in a service provider environment, manageability is key of success.